# Different behaviour between Android ICS and Kitkat when using findViewById

Tags: android, view, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.4-kitkat

I found a strange behavior of the findViewById method using two different devices (ICS and Kitkat). I'am using a Fragment activity containing a Custom support Fragment. The Fragment is added by using the Android FragmentTransation.

**Initialization in FragmentActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.voting_list_activity);

 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.activity_layout, new CustomFragment());
 transaction.commit();      
}
```

Now I'm inflating the layout in the Fragments onCreate method and initializes the ui references. This works properly with both devices and android versions.

**Initialization in Support V4 Fragment:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

 initUiReferences(view);

 return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

But now i'm facing the problem that i can not find the reference to an action bar item using findViewById() on Android Kitkat. On Android Ice Cream Sandwich this call returns the correct view of the action item, but on KitKat it returns null.

Any Suggestions. Thanks in Advance

**Edit:**
This is the initUiReferences. It only initializes a list view within the fragment.

```
private void initUiReferencesView(View view) {
 mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
 mListView...

 // This call always returns null on Kitkat
 View actionItem = view.findViewById(R.id.action_item);
}
```

Calling findViewById on fragment elements works without any problem, but when i try to find an action bar item it returns null. I tried it also to find the reference in `onResume` or `onViewCreated`, but it doesn't solve the problem. The action bar item is shown on the display and works properly.

Comment: show code for initUiReferences(view);

Comment: *initUiReferences* looks like `onViewCreated`

Comment: Where/when are you calling `findViewById` against action bar items?  If you wish to influence an ActionBar item after init, you should hook `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in  your `Activity` or `Fragment` then find the `MenuItem` by ID from the provided `Menu` object and adjust it accordingly.